# QAS custom address layout

Tags: .net

I have been given a new format to add to the QAS ini file Qawserve.ini and want to use this format in the GetFormattedAddress() method call. How do I specify that I want to use this new custom layout?

I have tried using the name as specified above the layout in [Custom Layout], for example:

```
objAddress =
    new QuickAddress(AppSettings.ReadSetting("qasServer"))
    {
        Engine = QuickAddress.EngineTypes.Singleline,
        Flatten = false
    }.GetFormattedAddress(Picklist.Items[selectedValue].Moniker, "Custom Layout");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The windows service for QAS needs to be restarted before any new configuration details are picked up.